# Laravel - Property [comment] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

i have a problem with laravel model relationship. The codes are as follows:

Route:

```
Route::get('/customers','Back\CustomerController@index')->name('admin.customer');
```

Models\Customer.php:

```
class Customer extends Model{
  public function getData(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Datapanel','name','name');
  }
}
```

Models\Datapanel.php:

```
class Datapanel extends Model{
   //
}
```

CustomerController.php:

```
class CustomerController extends Controller{
  public function index(){
    $customers=Customer::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    return view('back.customer',compact('customers'));
  }
}
```

customer.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($customers as $customer)
<div class="tab-pane" id="{{$customer->name}}" role="tabpanel">
    {{$customer->getData}} //this line working and calling all data of the same name, but in array format.
    {{$customer->getData->comment}} //this line is what I want, but it doesn't work and gives the error Property [comment] does not exist on this collection instance
    {{$customer->getData->first()->comment}} //this line working, but calling first data and i want all the data of the same name.
    {{$customer->getData->all()->comment}} //I wish there was something like but it donesn't work.
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `getData` is returning a HasMany relationship it will be a collection and not a single record. So need to loop over the collection to display data. See below

```
@foreach ($customers as $customer)
<div class="tab-pane" id="{{$customer->name}}" role="tabpanel">

    <!-- Loop over each record in $customer->getData -->
    @foreach($customer->getData as $data)
        {{ $data->comment }} 
    @endforeach

</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Yess you are a genius.Thanks for your reply I've been trying to solve for 2 days.

Comment: @ErdemSandıkçı Glad I could help. Pls remember to mark the answer as accepted/upvote for the benefit of subsequent visitors.